# problems with webhook telegrambot and flask in heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am wanting to create a bot for telegram and a web application from which I can edit and store the commands for said bot. The problem arises when I deploy in heroku, since I cannot run the bot and the web application at the same time. I think I am having problems with the webhook. This is my code.

app.py

```
import os
import sys

import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, updater
from telegram.ext.commandhandler import CommandHandler
from resources.commands import *
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

token = "Telegram bot token"
heroku_app_name = "Heroku app name"

bot = telegram.Bot(token= token)
app=Flask(__name__)

updater = Updater(bot.token, use_context= True)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')    

@app.route('/')
def webhook():
    updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                    port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)),
                    url_path=token,
                    webhook_url="https://{}.herokuapp.com/{}".format(os.environ.get("HEROKU_APP_NAME"), token))
    return "!", 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    webhook()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))

dp = updater.dispatcher

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("hello", hellothere))    

def hellothere(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello There!!")
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bot</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Procfile

```
web: python app.py
```

Log

```
2021-10-27T16:49:56.962690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py`

2021-10-27T16:49:59.445699+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-27 16:49:59,445 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler started,

2021-10-27T16:49:59.800346+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)

2021-10-27T16:49:59.800372+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Environment: production

2021-10-27T16:49:59.800373+00:00 app[web.1]:    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.

2021-10-27T16:49:59.800387+00:00 app[web.1]:    Use a production WSGI server instead.

2021-10-27T16:49:59.800399+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debug mode: on

2021-10-27T16:49:59.817520+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-10-27T16:49:59.817521+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 401, in <module>

2021-10-27T16:49:59.817724+00:00 app[web.1]:     app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))

2021-10-27T16:49:59.817727+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 920, in run

2021-10-27T16:49:59.817951+00:00 app[web.1]:     run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)

2021-10-27T16:49:59.817960+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 984, in run_simple

2021-10-27T16:49:59.818196+00:00 app[web.1]:     s.bind(server_address)

2021-10-27T16:49:59.818260+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

2021-10-27T16:50:00.329639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2021-10-27T16:50:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

comment out the line
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))

you will not have a /home handler
but the webhook will probably work listening on the Heroku supplied port

Comment: I understand, but my idea is not only to have a functional bot but also a front end that coexists with the bot. Is that possible?

Comment: you might be able to have the bot listening on other port ( it is just internally not available outside the dyno ) then you can handle the bot requests from outside to the internal port using some tunneling of the incoming request so that the bot will get to handle it using the internal tunneling

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 processes on the same port (see error) and you cannot use 2 different ports on the same Heroku Dyno.

You could use the Flask APP as REST frontend and, instead of the Telegram Webhook, you can use the `polling` approach (which does not need to bind a port)

Comment: hi, I did what you suggested, and I keep getting error.i change the if to use polling
`if __name__ == '__main__':
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))`
and the error it registers is
`Error R10 (Boot timeout) Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL status 137
at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=nameapp request_id=18415f99-490e-4363-a4ae-91d2e0cba8f6 fwd="201.212.97.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`